# Adding a caption to a graphic inside a longtable

Tags: captions, longtable, labels

I have the following `longtable` :

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{10cm}|}
    \hline
    some text

    \includegraphics[width=10cm,keepaspectratio]{\basedir some.png} 

    some text\\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Is there a way to insert a caption and a label to a graphic inside a longtable?

Or

How can I insert a figure into a longtable cell?

I have been searching for a while but couldn't find any solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that `graphicx` offers the `\graphicspath` macro, which does what you try with `\basedir` ;-) Furthermore always provide [minimal working examples (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) illustration your problem – you may use the `demo` option of `graphicx` since no other have your image files. There’s also the [`mwe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe), that comes with some example images …

Answer (score 7, accepted):

define

```
\makeatletter
\def\figcaption{%
    \refstepcounter{figure}%
     \@dblarg{\@caption{figure}}}
\makeatother
```

Then you can use

```
\figcaption{my caption}
```

where you have `some text`

Comment: That's what I was looking for, it really helped. Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

David's wise answer guided me to the solution. I am just improving his answer but I lack reputation points to add a comment.

First, it works also for `longtabu`.

Second, we can also add a table caption with:

```
\makeatletter
\def\tabcaption{%
\refstepcounter{table}%
\@dblarg{\@caption{table}}}
\makeatother
```

Then use:

```
\tabcaption{my caption}
```

Third, I strongly believe that one has to use `p{}` columns to get it working. In `longtabu`, I was using `X[]` columns and it didn't work.