# Apply a figure caption inside of a longtable

Tags: captions, longtable

I'm using the `longtable` environment to display a number of figures. I'd like to include a caption at the bottom of the first page as a Figure caption, not as a table (so that it also shows up in the list of figures, not list of tables).  I found in [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85919/adding-a-caption-to-a-graphic-inside-a-longtable) how to define a new `figcaption`, but I'm getting a "you can't use `\hrule` here" error when I compile the following code.

It works when I use `figcaption` outside of the `longtable` environment, but I need it to be at the bottom of the first page.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{longtable}


    \makeatletter
    \def\figcaption{%
        \refstepcounter{figure}%
        \@dblarg{\@caption{figure}}}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
    \listoftables
    \listoffigures

    \begin{longtable}[h]{cc}

    \endfirsthead
    \endhead
    \figcaption{This should be a figure caption}\label{fig:MyFigRef}
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot

     \rule{5cm}{5cm} & \rule{5cm}{5cm} \\
     \rule{5cm}{5cm} & \rule{5cm}{5cm} \\
     \rule{5cm}{5cm} & \rule{5cm}{5cm} \\
     \rule{5cm}{5cm} & \rule{5cm}{5cm} \\
     \rule{5cm}{5cm} & \rule{5cm}{5cm} \\
     \rule{5cm}{5cm} & \rule{5cm}{5cm} \\

    \end{longtable}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a caption to a graphic inside a longtable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85919/adding-a-caption-to-a-graphic-inside-a-longtable)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out - I just needed to wrap `figcaption` in a multicolumn parbox.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{longtable}


    \makeatletter
    \def\figcaption{%
        \refstepcounter{figure}%
        \@dblarg{\@caption{figure}}}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
    \listoftables
    \listoffigures

    \begin{longtable}[h]{cc}

    \endfirsthead
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\parbox{\LTcapwidth}{\figcaption{Foo}}}
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot

     \rule{5cm}{5cm} & \rule{5cm}{5cm} \\
     \rule{5cm}{5cm} & \rule{5cm}{5cm} \\
     \rule{5cm}{5cm} & \rule{5cm}{5cm} \\
     \rule{5cm}{5cm} & \rule{5cm}{5cm} \\
     \rule{5cm}{5cm} & \rule{5cm}{5cm} \\
     \rule{5cm}{5cm} & \rule{5cm}{5cm} \\

    \end{longtable}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't \captionof{figure} be easier?