# Longtable and figure caption problems

Tags: graphics, captions, longtable

I am trying to define captions in longtable enviroment.
According to [Adding a caption to a graphic inside a longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85919/adding-a-caption-to-a-graphic-inside-a-longtable) I should define:

```
\makeatletter
\def\figcaption{%
     \refstepcounter{figure}%
     \@dblarg{\@caption{figure}}}
\makeatother
```

and then use

```
 \figcaption{my caption}
```

However defining \figcaption produce the following error in texstudio:
"Illegal parameter number in definition of \figcaption."
I think there is a conflict with some package... maybe hyperref ?
What can I do?

EDIT

Thanks to David Carlisle there was a missing '}'
However, corrected the definition, and adding

```
\figcaption{lol}
```

after

```
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=0.1\linewidth]{image}
```

gives a new errors:
You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders. \figcaption{lol}
Missing number, treated as zero. \figcaption{lol}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \figcaption{lol}
Missing \endgroup inserted. \figcaption{lol}
....

What happened??

Comment: Please provide a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix. Please be sure to state which TeX distribution you use, which packages you load, and a minimal `longtable` environment that contains a `\figcaption` statement.

Comment: Your sample definition is missing a closing `}` it has four `{` and only three `}`

Comment: hmm Just saw where you copied that from:-) I fixed it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem: the trick is use \parbox{..}
e.g.:

```
\parbox{5cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) { \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{image} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\figcaption{label: lol.}}
```