# Footnote in graphic caption in longtable?

Tags: captions, footnotes, longtable

I have a figure (includegraphics) in a longtable and I have added a caption to it with the solution taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85920

How can I add a footnote to the caption of the figure?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% caption for figure in longtable
\makeatletter
\def\figcaption{%
    \refstepcounter{figure}%
     \@dblarg{\@caption{figure}}}
\makeatother
% /caption for figure in longtable
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{ | p{3,5cm} | p{10cm} | }
        \hline
        text here & text here
        $\vcenter{
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{/tmp/tmp.png}
            \figcaption{sometext\footnotemark{\footnotetext{another text}}} % error here
        }$
        \\\hline
        \caption{some caption}
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The above solution gives me the following errors:

```
/tmp/t.tex:23: Argument of \@caption has an extra }. [...footnotemark{\footnotetext{another text}}}]
/tmp/t.tex:23: Paragraph ended before \@caption was complete. [...footnotemark{\footnotetext{another text}}}]
/tmp/t.tex:25: Missing } inserted. [        \\\hline]
/tmp/t.tex:25: Missing \cr inserted. [      \\\hline]
/tmp/t.tex:25: Misplaced \cr. [     \\\hline]
/tmp/t.tex:25: Missing \cr inserted. [      \\\hline]
[...]
Too many errors. TeX stopped.
```

Comment: Where should this footnote be placed exactly? Just below the caption?

Comment: Just place `\def`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the optional argument. You don't want the footnote to wander in the listoffigures anyway:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% caption for figure in longtable
\makeatletter
\def\figcaption{%
    \refstepcounter{figure}%
     \@dblarg{\@caption{figure}}}
\makeatother
% /caption for figure in longtable
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

    \begin{longtable}{ | p{3,5cm} | p{10cm} | }
        \hline
        text here & text here
        $\vcenter{
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
            \figcaption[sometext]{sometext\footnotemark{\footnotetext{another text}}} % error here
        }$
        \\\hline
        \caption{some caption}
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place `\def`

So you will be like

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% caption for figure in longtable
\makeatletter
\def\figcaption{%
    \refstepcounter{figure}%
     \@dblarg{\@caption{figure}}}
\makeatother
% /caption for figure in longtable
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{ | p{3,5cm} | p{10cm} | }
        \hline
        text here & text here
        $\vcenter{
            \centering
           \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{/tmp/tmp.png}
      \def\figcaption{sometext\footnotemark{\footnotetext{another text}}}
           }$
        \\\hline
        \caption{some caption}
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: making a definition that is then not used does nothing at all.