# Adding a label to graphic inside a longtable

Tags: longtable, labels, ref

There are multiple images in my long table environment, however I could not find a way to correctly label all the images in this long table.

```
\setcounter{ltrow}{0}
\setlength\LTleft{-1cm}
\begin{longtable}{c m{2cm}@{\hskip 15mm} m{5cm}  m{4cm}}
%Do not change
\toprule 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Authors} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Configurations} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Observations} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Image}  \\ 
\midrule
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makecell{Bozzoli et al. \cite{Bozzoli2020},  \\ 2020}
&    

Water,\newline
Ethlylene Glycol,\newline
50$<$RE$<$14k,\newline
5$<$Pr$<$150,\newline
0.928$<$p/D$<$2.071,\newline
0.042$<$e/D$<$0.071.%\newline
& 
- Cross helix tubes is recommended for heat exchangers in food processing units.
&
\vspace{-4cm}
 \adjustbox{valign=c}{%
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Experiemental/Bozzoli2020.png}
    \end{center}}
\\
\hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makecell{Virgilio et al. \cite{Virgilio2020},  \\ 2020}
&
Water,\newline%\\
20k$<$RE$<$80k,\newline%\\
p/D=11, \newline%\\
e/D = 3.5\%, \newline%\\
$\varphi = 80 \degree$
& 
- $C_f$ is 4 and 7 times greater than smooth tube for discontinuous and continuous ribs respectively.
\newline
- Discontinuous ribs have reduced heat transfer compared to smooth corrugation.
&
\vspace{0.5cm}
 \adjustbox{valign=c}{
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Experiemental/Virgilio.png}
    \end{center}}
\\
\hline
\bottomrule
 \caption{Various tube configurations in literature.}
  \label{Table:paper-matrix}
\end{longtable}
```

This gives the following output, where each paper is aligned one below other, as follows,

[image: Table from longtable environment]

Now, if I do a `\label{Bozzoli20}` under the first image after `\includegraphics`, the number associated to `\label{Table:paper-matrix}` is shown instead, for all the images that have been respectively labeled.
Could anyone point to another method? I essentially want to refer to each or one of such images, and not the table.

I checked [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85919/adding-a-caption-to-a-graphic-inside-a-longtable) answers but are for captions, so did not work.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please always post full but minimal examples others can copy and test as is, not sniplets like this (3) It is not clear from your question what exactly you are expecting a reference to `Bozzoli20` to return

Comment: What should the `\label{Bozzoli20}` return? Which number do you want to see there? Currently your images dont' have captions, so there is no number assiciated to them and you get the table number instead. Do you want to get the referenc number (if you use a numberic cite style)? If  so, just use the `\cite` command as you did in the first column.