# Multiple use of figure number, ext4 warning

Tags: floats, hyperref

I'm getting the warning message:

```
C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdf
tex.map}pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{figur
e.0.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
\def\figcaption{%
\refstepcounter{figure}%
\@dblarg{\@caption{figure}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{center}%
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{center}%
\end{figure}%

\end{document}
```

I saw some similar issues, but couldn't find a solution. How to fix figcaption so the warning is gone?

(Note the problem is based on / due to the fix required for (I cannot remember seeing a problem at that time):

- PDF generation stops when image with caption is included in a table.(https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/441)

and based on

- [Adding a caption to a graphic inside a longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85919/adding-a-caption-to-a-graphic-inside-a-longtable)

).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's not clear to me why you are using `\figcaption` inside a `figure`. Why not use `\caption`?

Regarding your problem: The hyperref package patches `\caption` so `\H@refstepcounter` is used instead of `\refstepcounter`. Your `\figcaption` misses that patch:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
\def\figcaption{%
\H@refstepcounter{figure}%
\@dblarg{\@caption{figure}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{center}%
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{center}%
\end{figure}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check the results tomorrow. Just a small question on another question I was advised (@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz) to use `htbp` instead of `H`, wil this have an influence on the `\H@refstepcounter` change?

Comment: `\H@refstepcounter` is hyperrefs variant of `\refstepcounter`. There is no connection to the float placement `H` or `htbp`.

Comment: OK thanks. A bit confusing in this case both times the `H` but it is logical.